# How to set ENVFILE in Terminal to generate Android Release APK?

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native

I'm trying to build APK from command line in my `React Native` project. I've used [react-native-config](https://github.com/luggit/react-native-config) plugin to define my API URLs based on selected environment.

When I try to launch the app on emulator with the command (from `Terminal`), `ENVFILE=.env.dev react-native run-android`, app builds and launches properly.

But when I try to generate Release build using the command (from `Terminal`), `ENVFILE=.env.dev && cd android && ./gradlew clean build`, command fails with the log:

```
> Configure project :app
Reading env from: .env
**************************
*** Missing .env file ****
**************************
```

**Question:** How to build Release APK using ENVFILE from Terminal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try below

```
cd android && ENVFILE=.env.dev ./gradlew clean build
```

Comment: Thanks. Missed the documentation.